# Ассемблер: ошибка при вызове сегмента в сегменте

Tags: ассемблер

В после нажатия кнопки EMULATE всплывает сообщение :

> wrong parameters:call PUNKT1 jmp M3;

Помогите исправить эту ошибку!

Код программы :

```
Page 120 , 180;
TITLE Lab6.asm;

;------------------------------------------------
STACKSG         SEGMENT PARA "Stack"
                DB  256 DUP(0)
STACKSG ENDS




;----------------------------------------
DATASG           SEGMENT   PARA 'Data'
STR0  DB "press any key...$"        
STR1  DB "            MENU of prorammu ZVUK:"
STR9  DB "------------------------------------------------"
STR2  DB "1 - Generic zvukov pri naghatii klavishi $"
STR3  DB "2 - realiz zvukov s Random dlit i visotoy tona $"
STR4  db "3 - Posled zv-v c generic tonom ot low k high $"
STR5  db "4 - Posled zv-v c generic tonom ot high klow  $"
STR6  db "5 - Posled zv-v odn ton-ti ot short k long dlit"
STR7  db "6 - Posled zv-v zad polzovatelem"
STR8  db "7 - Exit is programmu"    
STRP1 DB "DLYA VIHODA PRESS BUTTON -- 7"   
STRP2 DB "VIVOD MELODIY"
STRP3 DB "VIVOD OKTAV SNIZU V VERH PO TONU" 
STRP4 DB "VIVOD OKTAV S VERHU V NIZ PO TONU"
INADR db 2 dup (' ');
INpunkt6 db 6 dup (' ');  

CHANN_B EQU 61h     ; CHANN_B - adres regista curcit 8255
FREQ    EQU INpunkt6    ; FREG - CHASTOTA
CYCL    EQU 30000       ; CYCL - KOL-VO ciklov formiorvaniya «1» ? «0»
DATASG ENDS




;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CODES           SEGMENT   PARA 'Code'
BEGIN           PROC   MENU
ASSUME     SS:STACKSG, CS:CODES, DS:DATASG, ES:NOTHING             
PUSH DS;SAVE STACK ADRES IN DS ADRES
SUB AX,AX;
PUSH AX; 
   ; set segment registers:
    mov ax, DATASG
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax          

   ;SET CURSOR POZITION
   MOV AH,02;SELECT POZITION CURSOR
   MOV BH,00;CLEARING SCREEN
   MOV DH,05;  STRING
   MOV DL,32;  COLUMN
   INT 10H;      
   JMP M1;

 M2:;CLEARING SCREEN 
    MOV AX,0600H;
    MOV BH, 7;
    MOV CX,0000;
    MOV DX,184Fh;
    INT 10H;
 ; output string at ds:dx
   M1:
    mov ah, 9 ;ZAPROS VIVOVODA NA EKRAN; 
    MOV AH, 7
    LEA DX,STR1
    INC DH;PEREVOD KURSORA NA NEW STRING
    LEA DX,STR9
    INC DH;
    LEA DX,STR2
    INC DH;
    LEA DX,STR3;
    INC DH;
    LEA DX,STR4;
    INC DH;
    LEA DX,STR5;
    INC DH;
    LEA DX,STR6;
    INC DH;
    LEA DX,STR7;
    INC DH;
    LEA DX,STR8;
    INC DH;
    LEA DX,STR9;
    INC DH;
    lea dx,STR0;

    int 21h     
    JMP M3;

   ;pole vvoda
   M3:  
    MOV AH,3FH;
    MOV BX, 00;
    MOV CX, 2;

    ; wait for any key....    
    mov ah, 1 
    lea DX,INADR;
    int 21h

   CMP DX,31h;
   JNZ punkt1;
   CMP DX,32h;
   JNZ punkt2;
   CMP DX,33h;
   JNZ punkt3
   CMP DX,34h;
   JNZ punkt4;
   CMP DX,35h;
   JNZ punkt5;
   CMP DX,36h;
   JNZ punkt6;
   CMP DX,37h;
   JNZ punkt7;

    punkt1: call PUNKT1 jmp M3;
    punkt2: call PUNKT2 jmp M3; 
    punkt3: call PUNKT3 jmp M3; 
    punkt4: call PUNKT4 jmp M3; 
    punkt5: call PUNKT5 jmp M3; 
    punkt6: call PUNKT6 jmp M3; 
    punkt7:

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CODES           SEGMENT   PARA 'Code'
BEGIN           PROC   PUNKT1; ZAPOLN 180 YACHEEK  ELEM MAS
ASSUME     SS:STACKSG, CS:CODES, DS:DATASG, ES:NOTHING             
PUSH DS;SAVE STACK ADRES IN DS ADRES
SUB AX,AX;
PUSH AX;

;CLEARING SCREEN 
    MOV AX,0600H;
    MOV BH, 7;
    MOV CX,0000;
    MOV DX,184Fh;
    INT 10H;

     mov ah, 9 ;ZAPROS VIVOVODA NA EKRAN; 
    MOV AH, 7
    LEA DX,STRP1  

    ;SBROS KLAVU 
    MOV AH,OCH;
    Mov AX,0000;   
    INT 21H;
c1:                
CMP 61H,AX;
JNZ  DO_N;
CMP 77H,AX;
JNZ  DO_D_RE_B;
CMP 73H,AX;
JNZ RE_N;
CMP 65H,AX   ;
JNZ RE_D_MI_B;
CMP 64H,AX;
JNZ MI_N;
CMP 66H,AX;
JNZ FA_N;
CMP 74H,AX;
JNZ FA_D_SOL_B;
CMP 67H,AX;
JNZ SOL_N;
CMP 79H,AX;
JNZ SOL_D_LYA_B;
CMP 68H,AX;
JNZ LYA_N;
CMP 75H,AX;
JNZ LYA_D_SI_B;
CMP 6AH,AX;
JNZ SI_N;
CMP 6AH,AX;
JNZ DO2_N;  
CMP 37h,AX;
JNZ exit;
Loop c1;
exit: ret;   


;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DO_N:
;generation noti DO
REG_B   ORG 61h     ; REG_B - adres regista curcit 8253
COM_REG ORG 43h     ; COM_REG - adres comand of registra curcit8253
CHANN_2 ORG 42h     ; CHANN_2 - adres chanak 2nd circuit  8253

    mov al, 10110110b   ; reghym 3, type 3, chanel 2, dan - binary
    out COM_REG,    al  ; write registr
    mov ax, 4561    ; 1193180(Gc)/261(Gc) = 4561
    out CHANN_2,    al  ; zapis mladsh byta in "zadvighka"
    mov al, ah  ; out CHAN_2, ah - it's not stayting!
    out CHANN_2,    al  ;  zapis starsh byta in "zadvighka"
    in  al, REG_B   ; Readin previos data from Registr b
    or  al, 03h ; Insert in "1" bits 1 & 0 of registr b
    out REG_B,  al  ; writing new data in reg_b
    ret         ; exit from program  
;==============================================================================
BEGIN   ENDP
CODES   ENDS
END BEGIN
```

Comment: Отредактируйте сообщение, пожалуйста, нечитабельное совсем.

Comment: а как правильно редактировать потому, что игнорирует переход на новую строку и все лепит в одной?

Comment: А под какой транслятор написано?

Comment: не совсем понятно слово транслятор, что вы имеете ввиду ?

Comment: Ну ладно, просто строка `punkt1: call PUNKT1 jmp M3;` не похожа на правду. 2 операции в 1 строке. Ошибка (если транслятор не экзотический)

Comment: если под транслятором подразумевается среда ,то пишу в emu8086.

Comment: Эта строчка явно неправильная.Делите ее на 2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38808/discussion-between-alexandr-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключалась в том,что две команды были написаны в одной строке , что неправильно. Также, была исправлена ошибка: заменена `end start` на

```
BEGIN   ENDP
CODES   ENDS
END BEGIN
```